# How do i have to define the if condition to check if the array_key length =13?

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment my "method" checks if the array_key is in the array, i need to add that if the key length is 13 it is okay, but when it is longer it has to delete the like first 5 numbers of the list. My code searches the price according to my key out of the database, and compares it to a list where the "keys" are a bit different. So to make it easier to understand:

The key in my database is: 2840529503100

The key in the table where i have to get the price from is: 000002840529503100
So what i basically need to do is get a substring from the "list" or "table" which takes the last 13 numbers because the right keys of my database are always 13 numbers long.

```
$teile = array();
while ($dbRow = $sqlres->fetch_assoc()) {

    $teile[$dbRow['nummer']] = $dbRow;

    if (array_key_exists($fileRow[0], $teile)) {
```

Comment: [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Why not trim off the 0's at the start of the strings and convert the key to `int` or `bigint`? You should fix the database instead of working around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first five 0 values is constant means you can use substr() like this:

```
$str = '000002840529503100';
echo $str2 = substr($str, 5);
```

Another method for `substr()` is only keep the last last 13 digits like this:

```
$str = '000002840529503100';
echo $str2 = substr($str, -13);
```

Else to remove the first 0 values you can use `ltrim()` like this:

```
echo ltrim('000002840529503100', '0');
```

Note: without quotes these two functions won't work.

Comment: Nawin, use substr($str, -13) instead. Your example will trim first 5 even if strlen() <= 13

Comment: That's why i mention "First five 0 values is constant" @MichaelEugeneYuen But yes you are correct.

Comment: OP says "if the key length is 13 it is okay"

Comment: $fileRow[0] = substr($fileRow[0],-13);

This worked for me, THANK YOU ;)

Comment: Happy to help you @R.You

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Nawins solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556886/3536236) you can also use [PHP Typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to automatically remove the leading zeros.

> NOTE: for my example; I can't see which variable you're trying to change. But assumed the first...

Thus:

```
$fileRow[0] = "000002840529503100"
(int)$fileRow[0] = "2840529503100";
```

This would make:

```
 if (array_key_exists((int)$fileRow[0], $teile)) {
    ...
 }
```

**BEWARE:** 
This example doesn't change the stored value of `$fileRow[0]` so using it as a *future* key reference (~`print $array[$fileRow[0]]`) will still use the longer number until the *`(int)`* version has been set as the variable/key value, *example*:

```
$fileRow[0] = (int)$fileRow[0];
```